# How to show php output values into Javascript var attribute?

Tags: javascript, php

In my php:

```
$result = $conn->query("select address, lat, lang from user where phoneno = '" . $phoneno. "'");


$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '"'  . $rs["address"] . '",';
$outp .= '' . $rs["lat"] . ',';
$outp .= ''   . $rs["lang"]        . '';
}
$outp .="]";
```

The value output from my php:
["Tampines Street 86, Singapore",1.3497658,103.9274115]

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];
```

The above is an example of how I want my php output value to be for my var locations. How can I do this?

Comment: One function `json_encode`

Answer (score 1):

**Do not** invent the wheel. Use `json_encode`.

PHP:

```
$locs = array();
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $locs[] = array($rs["address"], $rs["lat"], $rs["lang"]);
}
```

JS:

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locs)?>;
```

Comment: the javascript is in a html5 file which is separated from the php. I'm building a mobile app

Comment: And what? You output nothing from php? Then why do you use php?

Comment: I usually do https request from my html

Comment: function showcontact(){
                  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  var url = serverURL() + "/showcontact.php";
                  url += "?phoneno=" + localStorage.getItem("phoneno");

                  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                  showcontactresult(xmlhttp.responseText);
                  }
                  };
                  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                  xmlhttp.send();
                  }

Comment: function showcontactresult(response) {
               var arr = JSON.parse(response);
               var tbl=$("<form/>").attr("id","thisForm");
               $("#div1").append(tbl);
               for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
               var tr="<tr>";
               var chk="<th>"+"<input type='checkbox' value='" + arr[i].contactname + "'" + " />" + "</th>";
               var td1="<td>"+arr[i].contactname+"</td></tr>";
               $("#thisForm").append(tr+chk+td1);
               }
        }

Comment: Something like that

Comment: Then your `$outp = json_encode($locs)`. And I advise you to __edit__ question instead posting codes in comments, they're __unreadable__.

Comment: Okay so sorry! Anyway my problem is that becoz i cant do the functions inside var location which is why I'm stuck. Sorry I'm a beginner in coding